# Printing a PHP variable in HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP snippet which generates the required output in a variable `$ans1`. What I want to do is print this variable `$ans1` in a `<textarea>`. I tried to write the following code but it generates the output as usual and not in the textbox. The following is my PHP code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($submit3 == "Positive") {
        $ans1 = $row['reply_yes'];
        echo $ans1;
    } else if($submit3 == "Negative") {
        $ans1 =  $row['reply_no'];
        echo $ans1;
    }
    echo "<br/>";
    break;
}
```

And following is my HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="fetch_page.php">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Positive" onclick="enter()"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Negative" onclick="enter()"/>
    <textarea name="txt1" cols="66" rows="10" id="txt1"> </textarea>
    <script>
        function enter()
        {
           document.getElementById('txt1').value= <?php echo htmlspecialchars($ans1);?>;
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Please tell me where am I going wrong.

Adding quotes like this isnt working either

```
 document.getElementById('txt1').value= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ans1);?>";
```

As you can see in the following image, the answer(the not bold part) should get printed in the textbox also according to my html code 
[image]

Comment: Any error into your browser console? What is the type of this variable?

Comment: I ask for the type because if it's a string you'll have to add quotes around the value, something like this : `.value = '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ans1);?>';`. Also take care to escape quotes already included into the value, unless `htmlspecialchars()` does this job for you.

Comment: Stop posting the same answer everytime guys.

Comment: "Not in the textbox" is that because you're echoing the variable before using it in the JavaScript? You also specify a action to your post, so nothing will happen when you click the submit button because the pages script is halted to start the load of the new page. You need to clear the default submit behavior first, then do your javascript, and submit the form afterwards with `.submit()` See [W3C School Documentation on submit()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)

Comment: @JordanThompson there is no such thing as  W3C School its  W3Schools, more importantly note that w3c has no affiliation with W3School.

Comment: @AkhileshBhatia have you tried `document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML`?

Comment: @Musa You can downvote and have my comments withheld, but the fact of the matter is even W3 defines their standards as W3C, which is all I am referring to. There is no such thing as "W3 Standards" it's "W3C Standards": [W3C Standards](http://www.w3.org/standards/) / [Web Standards](http://www.w3schools.com/web/web_standards.asp) Which is all "W3C School Standards" means in my _link title_

Comment: @wasasquatch I see you're not familiar with http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: And for a website advocating educate, they sure have a few errors and bad implementation. Lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the text you want to be displayed in the textarea between the `<textarea>` tag.

```
<textarea name="txt1" cols="66" rows="10" id="txt1">
    <?php echo $ans1; ?>
</textarea>
```

If the text still doesn't appear or you get an error then make sure you access variables from the global scope. Like below.

```
<textarea name="txt1" cols="66" rows="10" id="txt1">
    <?php echo $GLOBALS['ans1']; ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Hey, using GLOBALS really worked....thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `quotes` around the echoed value:

```
document.getElementById('txt1').value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ans1);?>";
```

And your script should be situated in `<head>`
**Edit**
What about using this:

```
document.getElementById('txt1').value = "<?php Print($ans1); ?>";
```

Comment: please check my edits in the question. Adding quotes isnt working as i have displayed through the image.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't surround the php with quotes. The following works:

```
    <form method="post" action="fetch_page.php">
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Positive" onclick="enter()"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Negative" onclick="enter()"/>
        <textarea name="txt1" cols="66" rows="10" id="txt1"> </textarea>
        <script>
            function enter()
            {
                document.getElementById('txt1').value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ans1); ?>";
            }
     </script>
 </form>
```

Comment: Enter is called by buttons just before the textarea.

Comment: BTW It was my answer)))

Comment: Using json_encode is a better option than adding quotes since it automatically escape any quotes for you. E.g. document.getElementById('txt1').value = <?php echo json_encode(htmlspecialchars($ans1)); ?>;

Comment: @NoGray No. `htmlspecialchars()` is what you use. Especially to encode  quotes as json_encode() will not do. Unless you don't want to do that, in which case `htmlspecialchars(VAR, ENT_NOQUOTES)` will still be faster. That's why for handling HTML on JSON you still use `json_encode( htmlspecialchars(VAR, ENT_NOQUOTES) )`

Comment: Guys,please check my edits in the question. Adding quotes isnt working as i have displayed through the image.

Comment: Sorry I meant `htmlspecialchars(json_encode( VAR ), ENT_NOQUOTES)` @AkhileshBhatia , read my comment on your post. Your question on PHP isn't the reason nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

**Your question is not a PHP problem.** You can't see any output from the function because your script is halted upon submission! So change the submit buttons to `type="button"` and add a ID, then use the script below. Using jQuery (to minimize t he code you need to write) and use a timeout to actually have time for the function be able to display the results.

```
 $(".button").click(function() {
      var buttonName = $(this).attr('name'),
      elm = $(this);
      $('#txt1').val( buttonName + ' was clicked.' ); // Add response
      setTimeout(function(){               
           elm.get(0).form.submit(); // Submit form           
      }, 5000); // After 5 seconds
 });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MC9XY/)**

Comment: OK!
Will try this!! 
Thanks!

Comment: @AkhileshBhatia Updated to be more reliant and use native functions.